# How to include certain character in a regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I need a little help. This is my first time using regex.

So, I want to make sure that the user can only input a number and two other characters - period `.` and a comma `,`.

Whenever a user input a number with a letter like this `100A1`, it outputs "Wrong Output" which is great and that's what I want. However, if the user inputs `12.10` or `10,000` or `10,000.50`, the program also output "Wrong Output."

I am not getting the Pattern.matches() syntax right. I'd appreciate it if you can help me. Thank you.

```java
if (!Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", stringUserInput)) {
    System.out.println("Wrong input");
}
```

Comment: it is just checking if the string contains from 0 to 9. But how do I make sure the regex also check for comma and period? like what's the syntax for it? !Pattern.matches("[0-9[, && .]]+", stringUserInput) ?? Sorry I never used regex before.

Comment: Using regular expression may not be the right thing to do **in this case** and you should consider using [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instead. As the patterns will match for some wrong inputs too. for example, most patterns will match `1,000.0,01` as a valid input when it clearly isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work:

`\b[0-9,.]+\b`

---

Where:

`\b` - Word boundary

`[...]+` - Matches any character in the square brackets 1 or more times

`0-9` - Digits 0 to 9

`,` - Comma

`.` - Period

---

When I started off with learning regex, I used https://regexr.com/ to experiment. It has a helpful feature which explains what your regex expression is doing.

Hopefully this helps!

Edit: If you're writing in Java, you'll probably need to escape the backslash character. So the end result should be: `\\b[0-9,.]+\\b`.